# Sorting a string based on a word in a dictionary value

Tags: python, sorting

How can I sort the string based on the word value in a dictionary?

```
a = 'A B'
b = {'B':0, 'A':1}
```

Desired result:

```
c = 'B A'
```

What I've tried:

```
c = sorted(a, key=b.values())
```

But got an error:

> TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not callable

Is there an easy way of sorting words in a string?

**UPDATE**

After using:

```
" ".join(sorted(b, key=b.get))
```

I get all of the `b` values, whereas I only want to sort the ones present in the string.

```
a = 'A B'
b = {'B':0, 'A':1, 'C':2}
```

Produces

```
'BAC`
```

I would only need:

```
'BA`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to the solution. Unfortunately, a callable is different than a dictionary and `key` needs to be a callable (function):

```
c = ' '.join(sorted(a.split(), key=lambda v: b[v]))
```

Comment: this gives key error as ' ' is not in the dictionary.

Comment: @ChristianSloper you can replace `a.split()` with `a.strip().split()` if `a` might contain trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a list, but not strings, also you need to specify things as "elements of a list", as the keys of the dictionary don't map to a string...(there's probably a better way of phrasing this).

Anyway the solution is to split `a` and then apply the sort:

```
c = sorted(a.split(), key=lambda x: b[x])
```

Output:

```
['B', 'A']
```

For completeness:

```
" ".join(sorted(a.split(), key=lambda x: b[x]))
```